# Getting data from main UI to AsyncTask while looping

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm very new to Android programming (2 weekends). I'm finding it both fun and extremely frustrating.

I'm using AsyncTask with a loop in doInBackground that continuously polls a socket to receive and send data.

I want to send and get data from the main UI while this is happening.

I know I can use onProgressUpdate to send data to the main UI but how would I get data?

I have searched many posts and believe I have an OK understanding of AsyncTask  at this stage, to the extent that I know I should not be using it for this task :) but I just want too know if it's possible at this stage.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Anthony

Comment: AsyncTask is not something you should use. Looks like you are implementing xmpp in a bad way

Comment: Nothing to do with xmpp, just want to talk to a telnet server.

Comment: I would suggest a bound service then. AsyncTask is just not capable and good enough choice

Comment: Hi Hardik, thanks for the answers. I had a look at bound services, I think I need some kind of service all right, I will look into learning about them. I got around the issue for now by using global variables, I'm sure that is the incorrect way but I want to get back to getting my app going and having some fun.